# Can I Use TIP42 as Q1?

Tags: transistors, short-circuit, pnp

The Circuit Below is a **"Short Circuit Protection"**, and Circuit Detail is :

- Voltage Regulator: LM2576
- Maxixmum Load Current (i): 3A
- Output Voltage: 5,12 and 15 Volts

The Original Circuit is Low Current and Uses **"SK100"** as Q1.

My Question Is **"Can I Use TIP42 as a Replacement for SK100"**

This is My Circuit:

[image: This is My Circuit]

and This is the Absolute Maximum Ratings for **TIP42**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SK100 is a small signal PNP transistor 1A maximum, with a small base current maximum (tens of milliamps). The TIP42 is a high current power pnp transistor, with a base current up to 1A. They are not interchangeable.

Update: OP has provided more information, as they actually need to increase the amount of current the circuit can provide.

In this case, it should be enough to simply add the TIP42 in a darlington pair configuration. The SK100 would stay, and be used to turn on the TIP42. Disconnect the SK100's Emitter, and connect it to the TIP42's Base, while the TIP42's emitter goes to where the SK100's Emitter was. The Collector of both transistors should be connected.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fxktQZ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

You might have to adjust R1 to provide a better total gain, if 1k is the real value of it.

Comment: I Said the original circuit is low current (maximum 500 mA) but my circuit is high current (3A)

Comment: @HadiBarak you didn't add that you wanted to increase the current capacity of the circuit. It seemed like you simply needed to replace the SK100 with a pnp transistor you had on hand...

Comment: @HadiBarak check now.